# Water-gas shift reaction without catalysts

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium, reaction-control, fuel

I'm designing an experimental gas generator. The details are not really important here, but I want to convert a mixture of carbon monoxide, hydrogen and $\ce{H2O}$ gas to a safer form. I know the [water gas shift reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water-gas_shift_reaction) is capable of doing so, but I want to know if it works without a catalyst.

<strike>I do understand that the WGSR is an equilibrium reaction, and therefore will not get rid of the carbon monoxide completely, but I hope to at least reduce the amount. This setup will, of course, be done outside and I will be careful not to allow unburned $\ce{CO}$ gases to escape anywhere.</strike>

---

Edit: Someone pointed out to me in the comments that I can remove the carbon dioxide, a useless product of the WGSR, within the reaction vessel to shift the equilibrium towards the products. So the second paragraph is incorrect.

Comment: You can use sodium arsenite sscrubber to reduce the CO2 conc. thereby causing equilibrium to shift almost towards products side.

Comment: @JM97 That's toxic and carcinogenic -- I'd be trading one poison for another there. Perhaps I can use sodium carbonate.